# MySQL update table with faker generated results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb, faker

I have the contact table that i want to update with randomly generated
results:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| phone      | varchar(25)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So I use

```
require_once "/vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/autoload.php";

$faker = Faker\Factory::create('ru_RU');
$faker->addProvider(new Faker\Provider\ru_RU\Payment($faker));
```

to hook up faker and change locale to ru_RU

and then I loop over my database to change all phone numbers:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < ; $i++) {
    $phone = $faker->phoneNumber;
    echo $phone;

    $sql = "UPDATE contact
              SET phone = :phone WHERE 1";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':phone' => $phone,
    ));
}
```

In console echo prints all the different numbers, BUT all records in db
got the same number! Where's my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. Should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE contact
              SET phone = :phone WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':phone' => $phone,
        ':id' => $i
    ));
```

of cause.

Comment: It would assign same phone to all contacts for some reason. Had to do it this way.